# ggplot2 heatmap with colors for ranged values

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to make a heatmap in ggplot2. My toy data and code is:

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- 
  data.frame(
      Row = rep(x = LETTERS[1:5], times = 10)
    , Col = rep(x = LETTERS[1:10], each = 5)
    , Y = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    )
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = Y), colour = "white") +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
p
```

I want to have color scheme for ranged values like this:

```
-3 <= Y < -2  ---> Dark Blue
-2 <= Y < -1  ---> Blue
-1 <= Y <  0  ---> Light Blue
 0 <= Y <  1  ---> Light Green
 1 <= Y <  2  ---> Green
 2 <= Y <= 3  ---> Dark Green
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have several options for something like this, but here is one as a starting point.

First, use `cut` to create a factor from `Y` with the appropriate ranges:

```
dat$Y1 <- cut(dat$Y,breaks = c(-Inf,-3:3,Inf),right = FALSE)
```

Then plot using a palette from **RColorBrewer**:

```
ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = Y1), colour = "white") +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn")
```

[image]

This color scheme is more purple than blue on the low end, but it's the closest I could find among the brewer palette's.

If you wanted to build your own, you could simply use `scale_fill_manual` and specify your desired vector of colors for the `values` argument.

Comment: Thanks @joran for your reply. I wonder how to clear the lines between two rectangles of the plots. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Set `colour = "transparent"` in `geom_tile`.

Answer (score 52):

It's not clear if you want discrete colors or if the colors you list are just markers along the range of `Y`. I'll show both.

For discrete colors, use `Y1` as joran defines it

```
dat$Y1 <- cut(dat$Y,breaks = c(-Inf,-3:3,Inf),right = FALSE)
```

Then you can get a plot with the specific colors you list using a manual scale

```
p <- ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = Y1)) +
      scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("\[-Inf,-3)", "\[-3,-2)", "\[-2,-1)", 
                                 "\[-1,0)", "\[0,1)", "\[1,2)", 
                                 "\[2,3)", "\[3, Inf)"),
                        values = c("white", "darkblue", "blue",
                                   "lightblue", "lightgreen", "green",
                                   "darkgreen", "white"))
p
```

[image]

I didn't know what you wanted for colours beyond -3 and 3, so I used white.

If you wanted a continuous color, going from blue on the negative through white at 0 to green on the positive, `scale_fill_gradient2` would work.

```
ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Y)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="darkblue", high="darkgreen", guide="colorbar")
```

[image]

If you want fine detail control of color, such that the mapping is "darkblue" at 3, "blue" at 2, "lightblue" at 1, "white" at 0, etc., then `scale_fill_gradientn` will work for you:

```
library("scales")
ggplot(data =  dat, aes(x = Row, y = Col)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue", 
                                 "white",
                                 "lightgreen", "green", "darkgreen"),
                       values=rescale(c(-3, -2, -1,
                                        0,
                                        1, 2, 3)),
                       guide="colorbar")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brian for nice answer. You are wizard of ggplot2. Much appreciated your help.

Comment: Intriguing, despite 40 up-votes, when I copy and paste Brian's method for scale_fill_manual, it just wont work as shown in its figure.

Comment: @Aguscamacho Did you get any error messages? I got quite a clear error message stating that '\[' is an unrecognized escape in the character string.

Removing the `\ ` in the manual `breaks` definition works.

Seeing that the answer is six years old, it seems quite likely that the code worked six years ago, but has been broken by some update to R or ggplot2 or anything else.