# How can I recreate this graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a visualization package that I can use to recreate this 1st graph? I already try searching for one and I haven't found anything yet for that exact graph. [image]

I alredy tried using this package but doesn't output the exact graph which looks better for visualization, it plots the distribution in mountain ranges instead of the gray background like in the 1st graph.

```
ggplot(significant_genes_df, aes(x = mean_LFC, y = TF_variant)) +
  geom_density_ridges(jittered_points = TRUE, scale = 0.95, rel_min_height = 0.01, point_shape = "|", point_size = 3, size = 0.25, position = position_points_jitter(height = 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), name = "mean Log2 Fold Change") +
  ggtitle("Prolif 3 CD8 Day15/Day0") +
  theme_ridges(center = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What elements of the 1st graph are you specifically looking to recreate? This looks pretty doable in ggplot2 -- background as `geom_raster` or `geom_tile`, lines as `geom_linerange`, facet by the categories on the left axis, scale_fill_gradient to get the shading you want, etc...

Comment: Thank you! I also was trying to make it aesthetically similar, like having a rectangle mini plot for each value on the y-axis instead of one continuous plot as I have on the 2nd graph.

Comment: This link has discussion of one way to approach the background density plot to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31760486/16730940